# Deploying flask app online with ngrok got OS Error[WinError 193]

Tags: python, flask, ngrok

I have experienced this error caused from the subprocess module while working with ngrok module.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fierylion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\fierylion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 1306, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fierylion\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_ngrok.py", line 70, in start_ngrok
    ngrok_address = _run_ngrok()
  File "C:\Users\fierylion\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_ngrok.py", line 31, in _run_ngrok
    ngrok = subprocess.Popen([executable, 'http', '5000'])
  File "C:\Users\fierylion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\fierylion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Here is my sample code.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello Geeks!! from Google Colab"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue comes when any application you want to run needs python 32-bit version but you have 64-bit version.

Comment: hello, Thank you for the response. But the app run very well without `run_with_ngrok` module. If it was about version then the app wouldnt run at all